# ReactJS Array.push function does not work inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to clear the pointLoads variable first and then add a new array to it inside the useEffect. only the counter works inside useEffect. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TEST = () => {
    const pointLoads = [];
    pointLoads.push([5, 0, -10], [22, 10, -200])
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        "A": "9 ",
        "B": "19 ",
        "C": "9876 "
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        pointLoads.length = 0;
        pointLoads.push([formData.A, formData.B, formData.C])
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {pointLoads.length}
            <br />
            {pointLoads}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TEST;
```

Answer (score 1):

why are you using an array there if you can use a `useState` for the `pointLoads`?

Change the array for:

```
const [pointLoads, setPointLoads] = useState([5, 0, -10], [22, 10, -200]);
```

add set it: `setPointLoads([formData.A, formData.B, formData.C]);`

Answer (score 0):

this code is part of a larger code. I will use that table there in the future. I would like to keep an array if it is possible?

Comment: Instead of appending additional information as an answer (which it isn't), you could either edit your original post or add it as a comment.